# CSS subgrid buggy in Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-grid, subgrid

I have a css grid with subgrid. If i limit the subgrids height height of the original grid doesn't shrink. This is only in Chrome. Firefox and Safari work as expected.

[image: Firefox]

[image: Chrome]

[Here is a Codepen](https://codepen.io/kisfairmed/pen/QWoPMLo?editors=1100) of my minimal reproducing code. Have I done something wrong or is it really a Bug in Chrome?!

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  background: blue;
  overflow: scroll;
  max-width: 10rem;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.wrapper span {
  border: 1px solid white;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.3em 1em;
}

.sub {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: subgrid;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  max-height: 3rem;
  overflow: scroll;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class=outer>
  <div class=wrapper>
    <span>Foo</span>
    <span>Bar</span>
    <span>Foo</span>
    <span>Bar</span>
    <div class=sub>
      <span>Sub1</span>
      <span>Sub2</span>
      <span>Foo</span>
      <span>Bar</span>
      <span>Foo</span>
      <span>Bar</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Testing with Edge/Chrome on Windows10 it looks as though Chrome (so also Edge) is ignoring the max-height (or even height) when calculating the overall height of the parent.

Answer (score 1):

I just got a new Chrome Version and seems like the bug has been fixed. Somewhere between 121.0.6167.184 and 122.0.6261.57.

Answer (score -1):

If it works in the others but fails in chrome with no code changes, I'd imagine it is a bug. If you can't track down a solution to using grid, I'd suggest using flex instead - the example below shows how to adjust the implementation to flex instead.

Also, any users on windows-based browsers will see horrible scrollbars in your code example, making that interface completely unusable. You will want to test your output in that scenario - using overflow: auto instead of overflow: scroll will also prevent it from rendering unnecessary scrollbars (auto will only introduce a scrollbar when the content overflows, while scroll always shows both horizontal and vertical scrollbars)

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: blue;
  overflow: scroll;
  max-width: 10rem;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.wrapper span {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid white;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.3em 1em;
  width: 50%;
}

.sub {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-height: 3rem;
  overflow: auto;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class=outer>
  <div class=wrapper>
    <span>Foo</span>
    <span>Bar</span>
    <span>Foo</span>
    <span>Bar</span>
    <div class=sub>
      <span>Sub1</span>
      <span>Sub2</span>
      <span>Foo</span>
      <span>Bar</span>
      <span>Foo</span>
      <span>Bar</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the hints. It's just an minimal-reproducing example. The real application is checked for ux. Switching to flex isn't an option since the real site is a big table with no chance to realize with flex.

Comment: That's good, honestly you wouldn't believe what I see on some production websites where clearly no one involved in the flow ever touched it on a windows desktop device. Scrollbar city, or the entire site not fitting because someone did the whole thing in VWs and didn't account for the main scrollbar - I'd appreciate it to not have downvotes on the answer however. When a problem like this is truly due to a bug with grid in chrome, there is no true way to resolve it as a developer other than just not using grid. Hence the suggestion to use flex